# flow is going inside if condition even though variable value is null

Tags: java, freemarker, xsl-fo

If condition is not working and without out checking "if" condition it is going inside the "if" block and throwing below exception when variabel1 is null.

> freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:`enter code here`
>       ==> label.variabel1  [in template "crossborader.fo" at line 244, column 124]

below is the code

```
[#if label.field?has_content && (label.variabel1 == 'uk_image.png' || label.variabel1 == 'ireland_image.png' || label.variabel1 == 'ireland_RETURN_IT.png')]
<fo:table-cell number-columns-spanned="2">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:table>
            <fo:table-column/>
            <fo:table-body>
                <!-- SERVICE OFFER POSITION 3 & 4 -->
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell height="38mm" padding="1mm">
                        <fo:block text-align="right">
                            <fo:external-graphic 
                                src="url('templates/${label.variabel1}.png')" content-width="29mm"/>
                        </fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>
    </fo:block>`enter code here`
</fo:table-cell>
[/#if]
```

should not go inside if block if variable value is null.

Comment: With what are you processing that file? It is not XSL.

Comment: Are you misspelling `variable1` and `variabel1`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced in xsl, but in java you should always use the equals() string method to check if two string are equal. Also, you could simply check for null value as the first thing in the if condition. Something like`if !(label.variable1 == null) && ...`. This would ideally skip the if block since the first value of the && operator is false. This is basic control flow.

Comment: I've edited the answer as I thought best fit, please add comments on how to improve the answer quality.